# Powershell - Drag and Drop does not work when running as administrator

Tags: powershell, drag-and-drop

The following code does not work when I am running it as administrator. The files I drop to the GUI were not displayed on it.

If I am run the script NOT as the administrator it works. :/

Can somebody tell me why?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
Function DragDropSample() {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.text = "Drag&Drop sample"
    $listBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
    $handler = {
        if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
            foreach ($filename in $_.Data.GetData([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
                $listBox.Items.Add($filename)
            }
        }
    }
    $form.AllowDrop = $true
    $form.Add_DragEnter($handler)
    $form.Controls.Add($listBox)
    $form.ShowDialog()
}

DragDropSample | Out-Null
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, as an admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of User Account Control (UAC) in Windows. You can see the same behavior with any application.

For example, open notepad normally. Drag a text file onto it. It opens.

Open notepad as an administrator, try to drag a file. Won't work.

You should be able to drag between 2 programs running elevated, but as far as I know explorer never runs elevated, even when you explicitly tell it to, so you'd have to be dragging from some other application that works as a drag source.

Comment: This helped with an issue when running application from elevated powershell ...drag and drop handlers never even hit.  Ran powershell normally and bam, right back in business =) -thanks